# Package and download zip to Google Drive test

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api, jszip

Fiddle - http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/dodegW

I wanted to see if you can dynamically package a zip file and save it to Google Frive using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive).

I'm using the "Explicit render" method to start out with.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="render-link">
  Render the Save to Drive button
</a>
<div id="savetodrive-div"></div>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function renderSaveToDrive() {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
    var folder = zip.folder("images");
    folder.file("folder.txt", "I'm a file in a new folder");
    var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
    // see FileSaver.js
    // saveAs(content, "test.zip");

    // Save it to Google Drive
    gapi.savetodrive.render('savetodrive-div', {
      src: content,
      filename: 'test.zip',
      sitename: 'My Company Name'
    });
  }
  $('#render-link').click(function() {
    renderSaveToDrive();
  });
});
```

Whatever I try I keep getting, "Failed Download XHR error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be a Blob URL (with `URL.createObjectURL(content)`) or a data URI but that doesn't seem possible: [Is it possible to use client-side generated blob url to save to Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915648/is-it-possible-to-use-client-side-generated-blob-url-to-save-to-google-drive)